# Word Counter for Elementor form

Tags: javascript, wordpress, counter, elementor

I am trying to adapt a character counter to a word counted but with a space split that quits allowing type at the limit. I am using it with an Elementor form textarea. It works all the way until you get to 50 words and then everything disappears except for 50 characters. Not sure what I am doing wrong and too new to javascript to see the issue myself. Any help appreciated.

```
    // #form-field-custom_essay
// #word_counter
var textInput = document.querySelector("#form-field-custom_essay");
var wordCounter = document.querySelector("#word_counter p");
var wordLimit = 50;

wordCounter.innerText = wordLimit + " Words Remaining";

textInput.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
    
    var words = textInput.value.split(" ");
    wordCounter.innerText = (wordLimit - words.length) + " Words Remaining";
    
    if(words.length >= wordLimit) {
        words = words.substring(0, wordLimit);
        wordCounter.innerText = "0 Words Remaining";
        wordCounter.style.color = "red";
    } else {
        wordCounter.style.color = null;
    }
  
});
```

Comment: 50 words in a text contains more than 50 characters, why don't you not truncate to 50 characters when there is 49 words? where is the logic ?

Comment: I am trying to get it to stop typing at 50 words. The original script was a character counter, not a word counter. So, it truncates back to 50 character instead of stopping at 50 words which is what I need to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

substring function extracts characters, not words. You can try to disable typing on the textarea if the limit is reached.

```
textInput.addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
    
    var words = textInput.value.split(" ");
    wordCounter.innerText = (wordLimit - words.length) + " Words Remaining";
    
    if(words.length > wordLimit) {
       e.preventDefault()
        wordCounter.innerText = "0 Words Remaining";
        wordCounter.style.color = "red";
    } else {
        wordCounter.style.color = null;
    }
  
});
```

Comment: I guess this is a silly question to ask; but where do I need to put this chunk of code? In some particular file in backend in WP, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

you can do that...

**PS** `wordLimit = 4` for quick testing

```js
const wordCounter = document.querySelector('p#word-counter span')
  ,   textInput   = document.forms['my-form'].theTextArea
  ,   wordLimit   = 4 // or 50 
  ;
textInput.value         = ''
wordCounter.textContent = wordLimit

textInput.oninput =_=>  // use input event, not keyup event
  {
  let wordsArray = textInput.value.trim().split(/\s+/)        // array containing all textInput [real] words

  while (wordsArray.length > wordLimit )
    {
    let wrd = wordsArray.pop()                  // get last word
      , pos = textInput.value.lastIndexOf(wrd)  // find it in textarea
      ;
      textInput.value = textInput.value.substring(0, pos)   // trunc it in textarea
    }
  wordCounter.style.color = (wordsArray.length < wordLimit) ? null : 'red'
  wordCounter.textContent = wordLimit - wordsArray.length
  }
```

```html
<form name="my-form">
  <textarea name="theTextArea" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="type your text"></textarea>
  
  <!-- /.../ -->
</form>

<p id="word-counter"><span>0</span> Words Remaining</p>
```

Comment: I am using an elementor form so I am not able add an output line. I do have a text box with id word_counter that I am targeting in the original script to show word count.

<p><span id="wordCount">0</span> Words</p>

Comment: @Donna what the problem? you can adapt my code in anyway you want, the logic is the same. and by the way you didn't show your html in your question, I am not supposed to guess it

Comment: I am very sorry. Again, I am new to this and didn't mean to not include important information.

Comment: @DonnaTate you should read https://stackoverflow.com/tour , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ...and  Is that make my answer for no validation from you ?